# 4 div in one row , html , css

Tags: html, css

i set 4 divs in one row, i dont know rule for squencing div tags, but  I managed to set them.

`float:left;` apply to first,second and third div. Fourt div don't have float, because if i put float thats will change position of div, and dont will be 4 div in one row.
I think you will udrstand  me.

i tried to write in css display:inline-block; for each div of four but not working.

Can you check my code, and explain me rules for placing divs in row.
Thanks

HTML CODE:

```
 <div id="banner5">



<div  id="banner5About">
<p id="banner5Naslov"> ABOUT US </p> 
<img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/t62xkg.jpg" alt="Banner 5 Slika About"> <br/> <br/>
<p id="banner5AboutTekst"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>  
<br/>
<p class="banner5ReadMore"> Read More » </p>
</div>


<div id="banner5Linkovi">
<p id="QuickLinks"> QUICK LINKS</p>
</br>
 <ul>
        <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>   
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li> 
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
          <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li> 
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
          <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
         <li>&nbsp  &nbsp  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="banner5Latest">
<p id="latestNaslov"> LATEST BLOG POSTS </p> <br/>
<p id="latestTekst"> Post Title <br/>
 Admin, domainaname.com <br/> Friday, 6th April 2009</p> <br/>

 <p class="latestTekst2">
Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla.Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mia tellus consequat imperdiet. </p> <br/> 
<span class="banner5ReadMore"><p>Read More » </p></span> <br/> 

<p id="latestTekst"> Post Title <br/>
 Admin, domainaname.com <br/> Friday, 6th April 2009</p> <br/>
<p class="latestTekst2">
Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla.Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mia tellus consequat imperdiet. </p> <br/> 

<span class="banner5ReadMore"><p>Read More » </p></span> <br/> 
</p>
</div>

<div id="banner5Kontakt"> 
<p id="contactNaslov">CONTACT US</p> <br/>

<input type="text" class="nameTextBox" name="name_tb"/>  
<input type="text" class="emailTextBox" name="email_tb"/>  
<input type="text" class="subjectTextBox" name="subject_tb"/>  
<textarea class="textarea" rows="10" cols="33"> </textarea> <br/>
<button class="search_bt"> SUBMIT </button>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#banner5{
background-color:#1a1a1a;
border-top: solid;
border-width:7px;
border-color:#000000;
float:left;
}

#banner5About{
clear: both;
width:20%;
float:left;

}

#banner5Naslov{
font-size:20px;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding-left:20px;
padding-top:40px;
font-family:Cambria;
}
#banner5AboutTekst{
color:#676767;
padding-left:20px;
font-family:Cambria;
}
#banner5ReadMore{
padding-left:65%;
color:#0098FE;
}

#banner5Linkovi{
padding-top:40px;
color:#0098FE;
margin-left:5%;
width:21.8%;
float:left;
}

#QuickLinks{
color:#ffffff;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
}
li:before {
    font-size: 75%;
    content: '\00bb';
    color: #a29e9f;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#latestNaslov{
color:#ffffff;
}


#banner5Latest{
padding-top:40px;
margin-left:6%;
float:left;
width:20%;
}
#latestTekst{
color:#676767;
font-size:14px;
}
.latestTekst2{
color:#676767;
}

#latestTekst::first-line{
color:#676767;
font-size:19px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.banner5ReadMore{
color:#0098FE;
text-align:right;
}

#banner5Kontakt{
padding-top:40px;
margin-left:78%;
}

#contactNaslov{
color:#ffffff;
}

input.nameTextBox{
margin-bottom:15px;
    height:35px;
    width:250px;
border: 0px solid #a1a1a1;
   border-radius: 10px;
background-color:#232323;
}
input.emailTextBox{
margin-bottom:15px;
    height:35px;
    width:250px;
border: 0px solid #a1a1a1;
   border-radius: 10px;
background-color:#232323;
}
input.subjectTextBox{
margin-bottom:15px;
    height:35px;
    width:250px;
border: 0px solid #a1a1a1;
   border-radius: 10px;
background-color:#232323;
}
.textarea{
background-color:#232323;
border: 0px solid #a1a1a1;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "display:inline" for the div tag is not working because the browser have the default user agent stylesheet saying display:block. So, in this case, you need to override that style by using as follows.

```
div
{
  display:inline !important;
}
```

if you use like above, all the div will follow starting from new line. In this case, you need to use "Float:Left" for all the div's.

Editing for ReLeaf question:

if required,

CSS:

```
.styleone
{
  display:inline;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="styleone">
  Content
</div>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against using the !important tag here. If you're specific enough with your selectors you should not need to use it and doing so will make ALL of your divs appear inline which is likely not what you want.

Comment: ReLeaf: Yes. In that case, you can create a class and write your styles as I have mentioned now (after editing).

Answer (score 1):

your code works fine. what you have written in CSS is good in added to that you can add the following to look better

```
body{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
   }
```

and it's not necessary to add "float:left" to fourth div unless you add a fifth div.

Comment: Thanks man, can you tell me is it necessary to add float for main div, in this case he is called "banner5". Did i may always add float for main div or it's necessary only in some cases?

Comment: @nike992  No float is not necessary for "banner5" in this case.

Comment: Ok thanks.

@Vicki in which case need to set float for main div, when i said main div, i think in one main div i have a few divs?

Comment: @nike992 since the "banner5" is a container it does not need a float:left until and unless it is enclosed in some other div of similar layout.